# Codeigniter PHP multiple email, email fetch from mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to send email to multiple Receiptence i have multiple emails from mysql. 
i want to fetch in this format `$this->email->to('email1@xx.com,email2@xx.com,email3@xx.com');`

//controller

```
$data['admin_emails'] = $this->Order_model->saved_admin_emails();
$saved_emails = $data['admin_emails'];
foreach ($saved_emails as $savemails) {
    $to = $savemails['email'];
```

//model

```
public function saved_admin_emails() {
    $query = 'SELECT email from admin_users where state=1 and user_group="admin"';
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $dt = $result->result_array();
    $result->free_result();
    return $dt;
}
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::clear

Comment: All you're showing us is a SQL query (which I'm guessing works?) and the start of a foreach. You need to show us the complete code you've tried.

Comment: i am getting the emails from mysql like this admin@xxxx.com admin2@xxxx.com admin3@xxxx.com admin4@xxxx.com .... i want to pass those emails like this $this->email->to($to);

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->email->to(
    array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com')
);
```

use array_push

```
array_push($to, $savemails['email']);
$this->email->to($to);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => admin@xxxx.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => admin2@xxxx.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => admin3@xxxx.com
        )

)... i am getting like this i want to pass those emails like this $this->email->to('admin@xxxx.com', 'admin2@xxxx.com', 'admin3@xxxx.com')

Comment: I've tested it and the same result
    $to = array("email1", "email2",'email3');
    var_dump($to);
    $to2 = [];
    foreach ($to as $value) {
        array_push($to2, $value);
    }
    var_dump($to2);